# Tool to test websites

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm developing on super fast fibre optic connection.

I want a tool that allows me to test web sites at certain preset speeds for example - I want to feel the experience of my site loading at modem speeds, then perhaps 1mbps, 2mbps, etc.

Basically I want to be able to set the speed of the connection so that I get the real feel of the site loading remotely from other countries and connections.

Anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Super fast ADSL"!

Comment: I tried fire throttle, but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: How about using TOR and only using proxies in russia? :)

Comment: Don't just consider transfer throughput (mbps), though. Latency also makes a lot of difference (modems vs DSL e.g.).

Comment: What's your bandwidth out of interest?

Comment: FIOS in Czech is now 100mbps down, 10mbps up, unlimited, and affordable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WANEM](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) is a nice open source solution that can simulate Network delay, Packet loss, Packet corruption, Disconnections, Packet re-ordering, Jitter, etc.

It also supports a mode of operation that only uses one network-interface, which makes it super quick to set up a test environment.

EDIT

Although WANEM is a Linux application, you only need to burn the bootable CD and start a machine with that CD, no need to sacrifice a machine to run WANEM.  If even that's not an option you can also download it as a virtual appliance that runs in a VMWare Workstation ($$), VMWare Player (free) or VMWare Server (free).

However, in my opinion(based on real usage of such products) it's really easier to have the "network simulator" on a separate machine instead of loading it on either the server or the client under test.  And as explained above, thanks to the bootable cd option that can be any machine you have lying around - we typically use decommissioned desktops and notebooks for this purpose.

Comment: If that was a requirement you should have specified it.

Comment: You're right, and the post does not deserve to be downposted, its a good tool with some great options. So not sure who would downvote this answer.

Comment: Accepted answer for the effort!

Comment: Thank you.  And seriously, try wanem, i'm sure you'll get good results even though it's not a native w7 tool.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of tools outside like:

- http://www.netlimiter.com/
- http://www.antamediabandwidth.com/
- ...

basically the most of them work likes proxies